# Is there a way to have InfoWindow open on App load in Google Maps API?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, addsubview, gmsmapview

Currently my app opens a custom infowindow when the MapView delegate calls the didTap protocol. This then calls a function which initializes the needed aspects of the infowindow shown below ...

```swift
var tappedOverlay : GMSOverlay?
var customInfoWindow : CustomInfoWindow?
var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindow().loadView()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37, longitude: -77, zoom: 16.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView

        //this is where i attempt to force a infoWindow to open
        tappedOverlay = overlay
        initInfoWindow(overlay: overlay)
}

fun initInfoWindow(overlay: GMSOverlay){

        mapView.animate(toLocation: position!)
        let point = mapView.projection.point(for: position!)
        let newPoint = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
        let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newPoint)
        mapView.animate(with: camera)

        let background = UIColor.infoWindowBackground
        customInfoWindow?.layer.backgroundColor = background.cgColor
        customInfoWindow?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        customInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: position!)
        customInfoWindow?.center.y -= 100
        customInfoWindow?.CustomWindowLabel.text =  overlay.title
        customInfoWindow?.CustomWindowSubLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        customInfoWindow?.CustomWindowSubLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        mapView.addSubview(customInfoWindow!)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap Overlay: GMSOverlay){
        initInfoWindow(overlay: overlay)
}
```

Now I would like to have the app automatically open a certain infowindow as soon as it loads.

When I try to manually display the infoWindow on load by calling the function in viewDidLoad(), I have to comment out the `mapView.animate(with: camera)` line otherwise the map tiles will never load. Someone pointed out to me that the mapView methods have some 'background' information about the overlay when they are called, so I added the `tappedOverlay = overlay` line, this gets close in that part of the infoWindow is displayed when the app is loaded. However, this and all other 'regular' infoWindows appear without a background and not centered on the point and cannot be interacted with.

The infoWindow's are a subclass of UIView loaded from a XIB file.

The above code is what I thought would be relevant extracted from a larger code base. Let me know if anything needs to be added!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please share more code for better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this answer will help someone else. The issue was in the `mapView.projection` functions, they were returning essentially default values. I'm not entirely sure, but it seems when you click on a marker the mapView changes part of the `frame = ( 0 0;)` variable in the background, so this lead me to change the `mapView` initialization.

So instead of ...

```swift
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37, longitude: -77, zoom: 16.0)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
```

We need ...

```swift
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: LAT_OF_YOUR_INFOWINDOW, 
                                         longitude: LONG_OF_YOUR_INFOWINDOW,
                                              zoom: 16.0)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```